# Which algorithm for triangularization of algebraic surfaces with singularities?

Tags: python, surface, triangulation, python-moderngl

I want to code some software in Python that visualizes implicit algebraic surfaces with singularities (say the Barth Sextic e.g.). I am thinking about calculating primitive triangles in Python and then give them to a shader connected via ModernGL for the output graphic.

Since the most literature I found is quite old I am asking here what the state of the art algorithm for triangularization of algebraic surfaces with singularities actually is? I don't know much about the topic but I learned that the standard `Cutting Cube` and `Marching Method` probably won't work.